# Best practices for validating SignedXml

Tags: c#, certificate, signedxml

When would you use CheckSignature() - *Determines whether the Signature property verifies using the public key in the signature.*

over

CheckSignature(X509Certificate2, Boolean) - *Determines whether the Signature property verifies for the specified X509Certificate2 object and, optionally, whether the certificate is valid.*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml.checksignature?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Answer (score 2):

Generally, using the no-argument `CheckSignature()` is a bad idea.  It's only really appropriate if you also verify that the key in KeyInfo is "correct" and/or "trustworthy".  This is sort of hard to do... so, basically, never call this version.

The `CheckSignature(AsymmetricAlgorithm)` and `CheckSignature(X509Certificate2, bool)` overloads avoid this problem by assuming you've already decided that the input was a contextually-acceptable key.

(Opinion: Also, SignedXml is an archaic component based on a very poor specification.  Don't use it unless you have to to interoperate with something that is already using it.)